# web based version control with full management

Tags: web-applications, version-control

I am looking for a web app I can host on my server that allows me to create/manage projects using version control. I've seen some nice interfaces, but most of them just manage what you already have.(which means I have to manually clean up/set up things for each new project) An example would be gitorious, in which creating a new project actually sets up the repo for you. I'd also like it if it could support access control too for different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Top of my list would be [KForge](http://www.kforgeproject.com/) -- give that a try :)  Good luck!